# Dropdown Menu Disappears

Tags: css, wordpress

when you are logged in to my site, there is a dropdown menu when you hover over the user name greeting. There are three items in the dropdown menu, but when you move the curser between the second and third items (between Settings and Logout), the dropdown disappears.

Can you explain what is happening?

http://zanifesto.com

[image]

php:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) :
$user = wp_get_current_user();?>


<acct>
<ul>
<li>Hi </li><strong>
<li>
<a href='http://zanifesto.com/my-account' rel='nofollow'>
    <?php echo $user->display_name ?>
</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href='http://zanifesto.com/my-account' rel='nofollow'>Settings</a></li>
<li><a href='<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>' title='Logout'>Logout</a>    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</strong>

</ul>
</acct>

<?php else:?>

Please <strong><?php wp_loginout(); ?></strong>
or <a href="http://zanifesto.com/my-account">
<strong>Register</strong>
</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

css:

/***Hello User Name Dropdown***/

```
acct a {
 color: #e24949 !important;
}

acct a:hover {
color: #fff !important;
}

acct ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 1em;
left: 0;
display: none;
padding: 12px 0 10px 0;
background: #3d3d3d;
}

acct ul li {
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

acct ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: _“when you are logged in to my site”_ – I’m not, since I don’t _have_ an account – and I’m not gonna create one just to look at _your_ problem. When posting questions like this, you should provide login data for a test account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `z-index`. The slider on your page is `position:relative`, which causes it to overlap that part of your menu. Try this:

```
acct ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  z-index:100;
}
```

This will bring the menu back up to the top.

Answer (score 0):

An error like this typically occurs within inaccurate CSS and possibly some sloppy mark-up to accompany. Likely what is happening is you are defining your links and what is clickable poorly, allowing for areas that are supposed to be part of the link, not. Use your Firebug inspect element and toggle your styles to see what works. I notice your using a lot of padding. I would suggest reexamining your CSS.

This could help: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/